# How to prevent element to jump down to second row?

Tags: html, css

Pleas take a look on this example : http://jsfiddle.net/yU6qG/5/

```
<div class="left">LeftMargin</div>
<div class="right">RightMargin</div>

.left {
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color : red;
}
.right {
    float:left;
    width: auto;
    height: 300px;
    background-color : blue;

}
```

If you try to resize the window you will see that the right div will jump down a row. How can I prevent this? Also, why does nto left take up 100% of the height?

Thanks

Edit1 : sorry, that was not clear, this is for a responsive design, the right div will grow and shrink.

Comment: Because you specified height: 100%?

Comment: `height: 100%;` means 100% of the parent element, in this case the `<body>`. Note that the `<body>` is not necessarily the same size as the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/894Z8/3/

Firt there's not such thing as `height:100%` you'll need to do some CSS tricks to implement them, because this attribute means 100% of parent's height.

What you want is to display the div as a table, you can do it with the following CSS (incompatible with IE 6 and 7)

**Markup**

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="left">LeftMargin</div>
  <div class="right">RightMargin</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
    display: table;
}
.left {
    display:table-cell;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color : red;
}
.right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
    height: 300px;
    background-color : blue;

}
```

The div and class Table is optional, but for better compatibility add it. With this, you can expand the height of the div to the other one and it won't be reduced it when resizing the window.

Comment: Pleas see my Edit, % for the left div is not possible in this case.

Comment: Do you want to keep them one right to another until there's no space? If there is no space what it should be done?

Comment: Correct, thay should always keep there location and when there is no space left for the right div to resize it just stays at its minimum width. This will result in a scroll bar in browser.

Comment: I've added a new solution, please check it and tell me if this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

[check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/yU6qG/6/) The right div always covers the available space and does't get to next line upon screen resize

```
.left {
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color : red;
}
.right {
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    background-color : blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this style, You need to use all in % only.( not in px)

```
.left {
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color : red;
}
.right {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 125px;
    background-color : blue;

}
```

Comment: But what if left contains data and this data(image) can´t follow the responsive design. The % width on the left div will probably not work in this case? I have updated the source.

Comment: @SnowJim let me check. it throws 404 page

Answer (score 0):

Change the css on the right div

```
.right {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left:100px;
    background-color : blue;
}
```

For the right div to be responsive, you will need to apply a percentage. Fill in to your liking.

```
.right {
    width: 60%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left:100px;
    background-color : blue;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/yU6qG/7/

Comment: Problem is that the right div should be responsive in this case.

Comment: @SnowJim - to make it responsive it will need to be a percentage for CSS. If you like it to respond on the edges of the browser, you will need to "listen" to that "event", which will mean that javascript needs to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put a wrapper around it ;)

```
<div id="container">
<div class="left">LeftMargin</div>
<div class="right">RightMargin</div>
```

and your CSS is simple:

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3zUcZ/

Comment: What I need is the right to be responsive and the left to be static. Your wrapper with px will not work. Pleas see my Edit 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is what float does: push it left until no space is left, after that, put it on the next line.

You could use this instead:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left">LeftMargin</div>
    <div class="right">RightMargin</div>
</div>

.left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color : red;
}
.right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color : blue;
}
.parent{
    width: 310px;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
```

Comment: What I need is the right to be responsive and the left to be static. Your wrapper with px will not work. Pleas see my Edit 1.